# Query to get max insert stamp of each table from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

I would like to know how recent a table was updated on a daily basis.

Is there a more a efficient way to query the max(insert_stamp) of each table in a db without having to do this:

```
select 't1' as table_name, max(insert_stamp) as latest_update
from t1
union all
select 't2' as table_name, max(insert_stamp)
from t2
...
```

or something along the lines of:

```
use products
go
SELECT  st.name as table_name, ... (column name with insert_stamp)
from sys.tables st
where st.name not like ('staging%')
group by st.name
order by 1
```

Comment: If by efficient you mean query plan wise; no.

Comment: i mean using information schema from a db and selecting column where like 'insert_stamp'

Comment: Information about what data is stored in a table isn't in the `information_schema`.

Comment: @Larnu ive added another example in my question .

Comment: What exactly is "inefficient" about the first query? Reading between the lines, it seems you want a query that you don't need to adjust every time a table is added or removed. Is that the real goal here?

Comment: Why do you want that information in the first place? It's not really useful by itself. If you want to find changes since the last day, you can use [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and ask for the PKs of all modified rows since the last check (including deletions). That's *very* fast and allows you to join with the target tables to extract the changes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no idea about this and im not sure as a non-DBA  if i can do this.

Comment: @Smor i think he means inefficient in terms of redundant typing. Sadly, sometimes your SQL code will be a wall of text. Ive gotten over that a long time ago lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually really hate this but this is something I just typed up real fast.

1. I hate using dynamic sql for stuff like this but sometimes you have no choice
2. This probably couldve been a cursor or a recursive cte
3. also, ew gross loops.

However this will get you what you want.

```
SELECT 
    name
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by name asc) as ROWID 
INTO #tmp 
FROM sys.Objects WHERE type='U'

declare @count int, @rowMax int, @date datetime, @sql varchar(max);
set @count = 1
set @rowMax =(SELECT Max(ROWID) FROM #tmp);

CREATE TABLE #dates
    (
        name varchar(255)
        , timestamp datetime
    )

WHILE @count <= @RowMax
    BEGIN
        set @sql = 'SELECT MAX(insert_stamp) FROM '+(SELECT Name FROM #tmp WHERE ROWID=@count)+';'
        exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@x datetime out', @date out
        INSERT INTO #dates SELECT (SELECT Name FROM #tmp WHERE ROWID=@count), @date
        set @count=@count+1
    END

SELECT * FROM #dates
```

Comment: Thats seems neat but having error messages : Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@RrowMAX".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: One was obvious spelling error the other was me forgetting to declare @sql. I wouldve thought you’d seen that seeing how the error message is quite clear :) either way fixed

Comment: Uhm is it normal that i get NULL values in my timestamp col?

Comment: I dont know your data so i cant say.